# CAML - Understanding when to use Eq, Geg and Value

Tags: caml-query, caml

With the following CAML query:

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>');
```

- What is the difference between using `<Geg>` and `<Eq>` in the above query?
- Is this query assuming that there is a value in m list of 1 for the current ID?  I am trying to understand what Value Type Number 1 means?

Comment: Hi @blachawk, could you please rephrase your 1st question ? For the second one, this query is looking for the first 100 elements that have the "ID" column with a value greater or equal then 1.

Comment: My bad - it's now updated.  Thanks so far for the feedback!

Comment: Why the negative vote?  this a good learning moment fo something that is not clearly explained in examples I have found online...

Comment: I don't know how it happened. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @blachawk.

1- `<Geq>` means Greater than or equal and `<eq>` means equal.

2- this request is not assuming that there's an item with ID equal to 1. It's just looking for items which column ID has a value greater than or equal to 1, and it's looking for the first 100 elements that fulfill the last condition.